# Sentences preserved under inverse limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

One of the classical theorems of model theory is the Chang-Łos-Suszko preservation theorem that states that the theories formulated in FOL (first order logic) that are preserved under [direct limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) (generalized unions) are precisely those theories that are axiomatizable by a collection of $\Pi_2$-sentences, i.e., those of the form $\forall x_1 ...\forall x_m \exists y_1...\exists y_n ~\delta$, where $\delta$ is quantifier-free (see, e.g., [these slides](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/Onderwijs/Modeltheory_2012/slides_modeltheorie_lecture4.pdf) of Benno van den Berg).

The above motivates the following question concerning [inverse limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) (of inverse systems). NB: category theorists commonly refer to inverse limits as limits and direct limits as colimits.

**Question.** *Is there a characterization of FOL theories that are preserved under inverse limits*?

Comment: There is a gap between "inverse limit" as commonly understood and "limit" as understood by a category theorist. Do you mean specifically limits of inverse systems, or do you also allow products and equalisers?

Comment: @ZhenLin I meant specifivally limits of inverse systems. I added a parenthetical comments to clarify (thanks for your question).

Comment: The link to Benno van den Berg slides doesn't work.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov Thank you, the link is now fixed.

Comment: I do not know the answer to this question, but the notion of locally multipresentable category/ universal AEC is related to this one (it is stronger) and might be a good starting point: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09005

Comment: Nice question; but my off-the-cuff impulse is that I wouldn’t expect such a clean characterisation, since limits of inverse systems (if I’m understanding right that that’s what I’d call *directed limits*) in **Set** don’t enjoy such strong well-behavedness properties as direct limits of direct systems (i.e. filtered colimits), since **Set** is locally finitely presentable but not dually so.  Or to put it another way: I’d guess other classes of limits might give more natural answers consider than “limits over inverse systems”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I am in agreement with you; I suspect that there is a partial characterizations (by limiting to particular types of inverse limites), and maybe one can prove that the general problem does not admit a "nice" solution.